# Как можно контролировать количество данных, получаемых из SQLite, при их подгрузке, при использовании QSqlTableModel и QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, sqlite

[Есть пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a62e84d7eaaa5b989cc788b1833cb616c78e986d/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/test_sql_fetchMore__QSqlTableModel_QSqlQueryModel/main__QSqlTableModel.py) для [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) (для [QSqlQueryModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) код будет почти такой же):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery


db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('database.sqlite')
if not db.open():
    raise Exception(db.lastError().text())

TABLE = 'word2emoji'
query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec(f'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {TABLE}')
query.next()
TABLE_ROW_COUNT = query.value(0)


def update_window_title():
    mw.setWindowTitle(f'{model.rowCount()} / {TABLE_ROW_COUNT}')


app = QApplication([])

model = QSqlTableModel()
model.rowsInserted.connect(update_window_title)
model.setTable(TABLE)
model.select()

mw = QTableView()
mw.setEditTriggers(QTableView.NoEditTriggers)
mw.setModel(model)
mw.resize(600, 480)
mw.show()

update_window_title()

app.exec()
```

При запуске из базы считываются 256 записей и, при прокрутке вниз, подгружаются новые порции

Хотелось бы контролировать количество записей, чтобы меньше отображаться, например по 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ответ – нельзя.**

Это значение захаркодено ([см. `QSQL_PREFETCH` в `qsqlquerymodel.cpp`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqlquerymodel.cpp.html#_M/QSQL_PREFETCH)) и поменять можно только пересобрав `Qt`, либо сделав свою модель и в ней переопределить логику в [fetchMore](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore)